# If we preventDefault on mousedown, and double click on the document, then it is preventing default behaviour of chexkbox/radio label

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, double-click, preventdefault

This issue exists only in google chrome. If I have a checkbox with label inside a container which is having some focus styles. When I click on the label, I'm preventing moving the focus to container using e.preventDefault() but this is introducing one more issue. If we double click anywhere on the document OR select any text by mouse drag, then clicking on the label doesn't select the checkbox. But clicking on the checkbox directly does work fine.

If I clear the text using `window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()` it's working but doesn't allow the user to select the text of the label anymore.

Is this a bug with the chrome browser. I dont see any in the chromium bug forum.
Please check the code below..

```js
document.getElementById('chkLabel1').onmousedown = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
};
```

```css
.container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .container:focus {
    border-color: red;
  }
  #chkLabel1:focus {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container" tabindex="0">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" />
    <label id='chkLabel1' for="chk1"> with preventDefault </label>
<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" />
    <label for="chk2"> without preventDefault </label>
  </div>
```

Here is the fiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/zgz2j8ad/

Comment: always post the relevant code in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would seem to be this:

```
document.getElementById('chkLabel1').onfocus = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
};
```

This will only stop it being focused.